# Redirect a page id url but not the page slug

Tags: redirect, 404-error

My client is asking me to force a 404 `$wp_query->set_404();` if the URL is `example.com/page_id=342` but DON't redirect if the URL is `example.com/about` even though they are the same page. I have to do this in the `functions.php` file and not `.htaccess`.

I have tried:

```
add_action('init','add_get_val');
function add_get_val() { 

if (isset($_GET['page_id'])) {
    $param = $_GET['page_id'];
  
    if($param == '342') {
         global $wp_query;
           $wp_query->set_404();
           // status_header( 404 );
           // get_template_part( 404 ); 
           // exit();
    }

}

}
```

The code as it stands does not work. But if I uncomment the `status_header()`, `get_template()`, and `exit()` it does. However, it does not give the same 404 page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "if the url is `example.com/page_id=342`" - presumably you mean `.../?page_id=342`? If they are the "same page", why wouldn't you redirect one to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`pre_handle_404` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_handle_404/) instead:

```php
add_filter( 'pre_handle_404', 'wpse_383506', 10, 2 );
function wpse_383506( $preempt, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['page_id'] ) &&
        '342' === $_GET['page_id']
    ) {
        // Throw a 404 error.
        $wp_query->set_404();

        // And prevent redirect to the page permalink (pretty URL).
        remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
    }

    return $preempt; // always return it
}
```

Comment: this worked perfect, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! But I forgot to add that you should check if the current request path is empty, e.g. use `if ( empty( $GLOBALS['wp']->request ) && ! empty( $_GET['page_id'] )` - but you wouldn't need that if you want just any URL with the `page_id=342` to throw a 404 error.. :)