# 404 page is not the same when using PHP code in functions

Tags: php, 404-error

Based on a condition I want to show 404 page and I have the following PHP code in functions.php

```
function wpse91900_force_404(string $template): string {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
    if (str_contains($current_url, '/page/')) {
             global $wp_query;
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header( 404 );
            get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter("template_include", "wpse91900_force_404");
```

The output when the above condition matches is 404 page but its not the same 404 page that is shown when I enter a random URL like website.com/abc

The difference is in the headers. Most importantly the robots header in case of code based 404 is:

```
<meta name="robots" content="follow, index, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1, max-image-preview:large"/>
```

The robots header in case of wrong URL entered is:

```
<meta name="robots" content="follow, noindex"/>
```

Other notable differences are the title of 404 page, wrong url 404 page has breadcrumbs where as the 404 page shown by above code doesn't.

[image]

Comment: You should instead use the [`pre_handle_404` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_handle_404/) - see example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/383507). But why are you doing this - or are you sure you want to 404 all URLs having a `/page/`, e.g. `example.com/page/2/` and `example.com/category/foo/page/2/`?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes I want to 404 all urls containing the string /page/ at any place in the URL. So my code above is throwing 404 for all such cases but this 404 is different from a 404 shown when user enters invalid URL in browser. Since in my code, I am already inside the function for template_include filter, how do I plug the pre_handle_404 filter in my case?

Comment: I've posted 2 examples, so comment out your `add_filter()` code and try any of my examples. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template_include` is a filter hook, so you are supposed to always return the full absolute filesystem path to a template, and not doing the `get_template_part()` *and* `exit` calls.

And as for setting the 404 status, I would instead use the [`pre_handle_404` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_handle_404/), but the [`wp` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) can also be used: <sub>(note that these examples are not using PHP 8 syntaxes/functions, and secondly, I'm checking against the request *path* and not the full URL)</sub>

- **Using the `pre_handle_404` filter:**

  ```php
  add_filter( 'pre_handle_404', 'my_filter_pre_handle_404', 1, 2 );
  function my_filter_pre_handle_404( $preempt, $wp_query ) {
      global $wp;
      if ( false !== strpos( $wp->request, '/page/' ) ) {
          $wp_query->set_404();
          status_header( 404 );
      }

      return $preempt;
  }
  ```
- **Using the `wp` action:**

  ```php
  add_action( 'wp', 'my_action_wp', 1 );
  function my_action_wp( $wp ) {
      global $wp_query;
      if ( false !== strpos( $wp->request, '/page/' ) ) {
          $wp_query->set_404();
          status_header( 404 );
      }
  }
  ```

So whichever option you chose, you should now see the proper 404 headers and template, just like what we would see when visiting a page which truly did not exist.